# Running nest.js from VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

So, I'm playing around with this new framework http://nestjs.com/ who seems pretty awesome since it allows the usage of Typescript on Node, very likely to angular.

Using the starter https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-typescript-starter, I can run it with `npm run start` without any problem, but since there is a .vscode on the project, I assumed I could use VS Code to run and gain some debug abilities.

The problem is that when I run directly from VS Code, without changing anything in the code, I get the following problem:

`Error: Cannot find module 'nest.js'`

I tried to run from VS Code with and without it running from NPM, no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently changing the launch.json to be `"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\index.js"` instead of `"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\server.ts"` and removing `outFiles` did the job. I will leave it here to see if it's correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated `nest-typescript-starter` today. The previous version had an old `dist` directory, with outdated imported packages. If you want to compile your application, use `npm run start:prod` script.

Answer (score 4):

To debug with nestjs app.
In 2020, after I follow [first-step](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps).
In VS code change default setting from:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/start",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

to this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
  ]
```

And press F5 to debug.
It works perfectly with me.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a `launch.json`. There is one described at https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/776

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\main.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```