# Debugging nest.js application with vscode

Tags: typescript

I am testing the nest.js framework but I am struggling to run it with VSCode so that I can properly debug my code. This is pretty much the same issue as described here [Running nest.js from VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078305/running-nest-js-from-vs-code). However I made sure I am using the latest packages. I always get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cats/cats.module'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\Documents\random-api\dist\app.module.js:11:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

`npm run start` works completely perfect, but I want to debug the application with the VSCode IDE.

**My package.json dependencies:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^4.6.6",
    "@nestjs/core": "^4.6.6",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^4.6.6",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^4.6.6",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^4.6.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.4",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "prettier": "^1.11.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.1.3",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "^5.0.3"
  },
```

**My vscode's launch.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\main.js",
            "smartStep": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the same launch.json with the typescript file as path, but that threw the same exception:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\main.ts",
```

Comment: so i you have made sure all dependencies are there, make sure that all your vs code plugin are update. sometimes a buggy plugin cause the vs code to give such error,

Comment: Vscode and all plugins are up to date.

Comment: I figured that it's related to the "relative imports". When I use `import { PlayersModule } from './players/players.module';` instead of `import { PlayersModule } from 'players/players.module';` it works fine.

Comment: This is what worked for me : [Step by step instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285180/debug-nestjs-application-with-nodemon-in-vs-code/60538988#60538988)

Comment: Here are step by step instructions that worked for me: [Step by step instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285180/debug-nestjs-application-with-nodemon-in-vs-code/60538988#60538988)

Comment: In my case, there was a bug with the IDE and nest start needed to be run twice for the code and symbols to be right for debugging.  There has to be a way for fix this, but knowing this was useful to get debugging to work.  The compiled js code and js.map files needs to be in the dist folder or breakpoints will be out of sync with what is running.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you also need to register tsconfig-paths when using module aliasing, like so:
"runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register"],
otherwise the debugger will yell "cannot find module ...".
If you agree, would you please update your answer ?

Comment: It worked. I have upvoted for this response. However, it does not run the application in watch mode. Is there any way to run it in watch mode?

Comment: To run the app in watch mode run this command ->  ```npm run start:dev ```.
you will find all the configurations in package.json

Comment: Can not work with nest global module. How fix isuse

Comment: @Saurabh47g unclear. How to use npm run start:dev from the launch.json?

Comment: @PptSbzzgt just write the statement in the Terminal.

Comment: It works. But you have to pay attention to @Bob s comment if you have module aliasing.

Comment: "Property protocol is not allowed."

Answer (score 97):

No need to mess up with `.vscode/launch.json`, just follow the official [Auto Attach intro](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach-feature) and ... Just Works!

For example, I wanna debug my project `quiz`:

1. Toggle "Auto Attach" to "On"

[image: Toggle Auto Attach]

2. Start a new terminal window (or restart)
3. Run the app as usual, for this project is `npm run server:dev`
4. When the app started successfully, attach to the process

[image: Attach to Node process]

5. See the first one? Click on it! Done! Now you can click on breakpoints and inspect!

[image: Pick the process]

Comment: Fantastic! This worked for me even only following first step. I had my nestjs app already launched in debug mode (npm run start:debug). So pressed Ctrl+Shift+P and typed "Auto Attach", select and Voilá, I can set breakpoints and debugger statements!! Thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as Accepted answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the simplest and go-to solution for all my projects.

Comment: This is the simplest answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just works :) this is the most straight forward answer

Comment: It is necessary to restart your terminal after enabling Auto Attach

Comment: @Steffen's comment helped me additionally.

Comment: Works in Aug, 2023. Fantastic!

Answer (score 93):

I tried the accepted answer and all the other variances and none worked for me, however what really works for me is to attach to the 9229 port. What I did is add/modify your `launch.json` with the following config

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach NestJS WS",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "protocol": "inspector"
    }
  ]
}
```

and in `package.json` (Nest new CLI commands, requires `6.8.x` and higher, see this [blog](https://trilon.io/blog/announcing-nestjs-monorepos-and-new-commands#Migration-strategy))

```json
{
  "name": "nest-app",
  "scripts": {
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch"
  }
}
```

and finally it works!

Comment: Works beautifully, thx! I kind of prefer attaching to a running instance as I find it less intrusive.

Comment: If you go to Settings => Debug › Node: Auto Attach and turn it on, VSCode will auto-attach when you run `npm run start:debug` in the integrated terminal.

Comment: @JWess I just tried what you mentioned, and doesn't work

Comment: This! Attaching a debugger to an already running process always seems easier.

Comment: I would say this should be the correct answer as its using native nest config and only using vscode as a tool (as its supposed to be)

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot! It worked for me too!
I've read 5 articles but only your solution works with auto reloading of the app

Answer (score 41):

If you want to have log output in terminal + all debug capabilities, you can start + attach using npm, here is config for launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Nest Debug",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "run",
    "start:debug",
    "--",
    "--inspect-brk"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "restart": true,
  "protocol": "auto",
  "port": 9229,
  "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
},
```

Will show full log output in console + debugging

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far out of the box for new NestJS users. This compiles, debugs, and watches for changes to files in my project. Everything else misses one or the other from someone just learning NestJS.

Comment: Omg this is the best solution. This should the up-voted answer here.

Comment: Works great, just create a launch.json from the vscode "run and debug" window accessible from the side menu or better known as the activity bar and paste this into "configurations": []. Thank you @Sasha Ladnov

Comment: It works for me. It's the best solution!

Comment: It works, but I got warings say property **protocal** and **port** is not allowed. Removing these two properties also work, so maybe it's not necessary.

Comment: As mentioned above, `protocol` and `port` shouldn't be required. `restart` and `autoAttachChildProcesses` don't seem to be required either. I've also removed the `--inspect-brk` option and it's still working, does anybody know what it's for?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a config that works. Hope this helps someone :)

Make sure you add `tsconfig-paths/register` line under `runtimeArgs` else you will get an error saying some of your user defined modules were not found.

Also replace `<YOUR_APP_ROOT_FOLDER>` name with your application folder name if you have one under your root project folder, else remove it from the path in the script.

***Note:** Make sure to stop running your app before executing this debug config on vscode, because this debug script will launch a new instance of your app on the same port.*

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/<YOUR_APP_ROOT_FOLDER>/src/main.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy",
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "-r",
                "tsconfig-paths/register"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/<YOUR_APP_ROOT_FOLDER>",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This settings works for me

```
{
  "name": "Launch app",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "args": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "-r",
    "ts-node/register",
    "-r",
    "tsconfig-paths/register"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "local",
    "NODE_PORT": "9000"
  },
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "console": "internalConsole",
  "outputCapture": "std"
}
```

Get it from [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1543)

Answer (score 5):

For people using [Nrwl](https://nx.dev/angular):

**Launch.json** (courtesy of [@ghiscoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357642/991219) )

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach NestJS WS",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "protocol": "inspector"
    }
```

**Terminal**

```
ng serve nestjs_project --port 9229
```

Comment: this worked for me in a Nx workspace without the launch.json but with Auto Attach set to on. if you omit the port parameter, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Add this configuration to launch.json

```
 {
      "name": "npm run start:debug",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "start:debug"],
      "port": 9229,
      "env": {
        "PORT": "5000" // env var used in app        
      }
    },
```

This will be with watch mode so whatever changes are made to `.ts` files  it reflects immediately
and makes sure you have the following script in package.json

```
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch"
```

This will start the app in debug mode and attach debugger

Answer (score 4):

No need to mess up with .vscode/launch.json.
Just two steps:

1. `Alt + Shift + P` open command bar.
2. Toggle `Debug: Toggle Auto Attach` to `On`(smart,always....).

Then `reopen` terminal and start your debugge like in browser.

Answer (score 3):

in launch.json have

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
        "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "protocol": "inspector"
    }
   ]
  }
```

Comment: have edited to reflect what am using at the time of this writing

Answer (score 3):

If you get an error like this

> could not read source map for node_modules / typescript / lib /
> typescript.js

setting the **"type"** to *"pwa-node"* instead of *"node"*

If you get an error like this

> Cannot find module src/interceptors/auth.interceptor

setting the **"runtimeArgs"** to

```
      [
        "--nolazy",
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "-r",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
      ]
```

instead of

```
[
   "--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"
]
```

Result:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy",
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "-r",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      //   "protocol": "inspector"
    }
  ],
  "resolveSourceMapLocations": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "!**/node_modules/**"]
}
```

**BUT** I use this config

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
          "args": [
              "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"
          ],
          "runtimeArgs": [
              "--nolazy",
              "-r",
              "ts-node/register",
              "-r",
              "tsconfig-paths/register"
          ],
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "console": "integratedTerminal",
          "protocol": "inspector"
      },
      {
        "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect-brk", "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest", "--runInBand", "--coverage", "false"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks this site: [Click me](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/debugging-nestjs-in-vscode-d474a088c63b)

Answer (score 3):

This config should do the trick

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "npm dev",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "start:dev"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was auto attach the vs code debugging process with one of my scripts in package.json. And on top of it I used nodemon, which would automatically restart up along with the debugger, if you have made any changes in development.

The process requires you to install nodemon globally and add a nodemon-debug.json file in the root of the folder, which looks like this.

**nodemon-debug.json**

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register src/main.ts"
}
```

Then in the package.json, add a script that looks like this

```
"debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json"
```

Then in the VS Code, hit **F1** > search for **Debug: Toggle Auto Attach**. Hit on it to enable it.

Then start up the debugging process by running the following command -

```
npm run debug
```

The debugger automatically turns on.

The advantage of this process is nodemon, which automatically starts along with the debugger every time you make some changes in the code and need it up.

For a more detailed explanation, go through this [link](https://nicholaspretorius.github.io/til0060/). Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just have to "promote" [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504765/debugging-nest-js-application-with-vscode/60231534#comment104790504_58357642) by @JWess to a real answer (and update it with the current location of the relevant setting) so it may be found more easily (this worked for me out of the box for a newly generated nest project, without changing any other configuration or file):

If you go to `Settings > Extensions > Node debug` and look for the setting `Debug › Node: Auto Attach` and turn it on, VSCode will auto-attach when you run `npm run start:debug` (i.e. `nest start --debug --watch`) in the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NestJs app in an [Nx Workspace](https://nrwl.io/) (Nx version 11.6.3), and it worked for me without using any launch.json settings.

In VS Code I have just enabled Auto Attach > Smart and I ran my NestJS app with the following command: 
 `nx serve <nest-js-app-name> --inspect=inspect --port=9229` 
 and VS Code automatically attaches the debugger.

My launch.json has a configuration to launch my frontend application while the above process automatically attaches the debugger when you start the NestJS application. This way I have both frontend and backend launched at the same time for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Add this configuration to `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch NestJS",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js",
  "args": [
    "start",
    "--tsc"
  ],
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "<node_internals>/**"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to spend too much time in getting the right `launch.json` file for your nestjs project and want to debug something in the startup process, you can still use the "attach debugger" approach using temporarily the method in your code `waitForDebugger()` available since [v12.7.0](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#inspectorwaitfordebugger). Then, you just need to run your `start:debug` script and attach the debugger using the VS Code command palette.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is working for me with Nest v10:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
        "runtimeArgs": ["nest", "start", "--watch"],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
      }
    ]
}
```

The most important part is outFiles. It allows VS code to find your source maps that are generated in the dist folder.

You can also use npm script instead of npx:

```
{
    ...
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": ["run", "start:dev"],
}
```

If you are using a multi-root workspace in VS code, specify your folder name: "${workspaceFolder}" becomes "${workspaceFolder:folder-name}"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to auto-attach, it's also possible to start the app directly in [JavaScript Debug Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_javascript-debug-terminal)

The naming of the command has changed compared to docs, Ctrl+Shift+P for "debug" and it will appear.

Basically, place a breakpoint, open the terminal, run the server as usual (even in monorepo workspace) and debug.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more approach that worked for me is with these launch.json settings.

- Disable Auto attach in VS Code
- Run NestJS application
- Now press F5, VS Code then attaches to the debugger
- You can now debug :)

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}
```