# debug nestJS application with nodemon in VS Code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, nestjs, nodemon

Is there a way to debug a nestJS project with nodemon.

i tried this code in launch.json

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "NestJs Watch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start:dev"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "port": 3000
    }
```

but i got this error

and my nodemon.json file

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node -r --inspect=3000 tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If we want to work in the debug mode, with a better chance to see what is happening in the code, we need to use "*nodemon*" with dedicated a "*nodemon.json*" configuration file to run our development "*nestjs*" server with the ts-node module hooking up the typescript compiler.

The steps that worked for me are:

- Install nodemon and ts-node:

> npm i --save-dev nodemon ts-node

- Next, add a nodemon.json file with debug and ts-node support in the root of your project:

> file: (project root) nodemon.json

- and insert this config. JSON text:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "node --inspect-brk -r ts-node/register src/main.ts"
}
```

- Next adjust file: package.json  - section: "start:debug"

> file: (project root)  package.json

- The original value typically is:

```
...
> "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
...
```

- Change it to:

```
...
> "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon.json"
...
```

- Now, in VSC (Visual Studio Code) make sure that you can see on the very bottom status bar:

  > "Auto Attach: On"

if not, on your keyboar press the keys:

> Ctrl + Shift + p

to open the Command Palette, and paste in this command:

> Debug: Toggle auto attach

and press Enter.

Now you should see the:

> "Auto Attach: On"

- Now debugging with break points should work.
- Start with placing a break point in the beginning of your program code
  (to make sure the flow does not end before your breakpoint ...)

> file: (project root) 'main.ts'

```
> function:  bootstrap() {

    console.log('test'); // -- place break point here

  // ... other code ...
}
```

- In VSC (Visula Studio Code) select menu item:

> Start debugging (or F5)

and select Node.js as the Environment option in the popup menu.

The breakpoint should be caught now in the bootstrap() function.

Answer (score 3):

I run this command:

```
npm run start:dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this nodemon config:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register src/main.ts"
}
```

and then you can run: nodemon --config nodemon.json