# while debugging in vscode changes in nestjs file does not take effect

Tags: node.js, nestjs, vscode-debugger, nodemon

I have a nestjs project in vscode and in debugging mode the changes in code does not take effect. Breakpoints hit normally, however, but for example a changed variable values are not to be seen - i.e. they stay as the previous ones (the ones before change).

My launch.json is the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
        "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register", "--config", "nodemon-debug.json"],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts",
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
        "restart": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

And the nodemon-debug.json file has the following:

```
{
"watch": ["src"],
"ext": "ts, js",
"ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

And strangely enough, when I make change in the code, the nodemon really registers it and restart the app, as can seen from the console:

```
C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd --nolazy -r ts-node/register --config nodemon-debug.json .\dist\main.js
[nodemon] 2.0.18
c:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\utils\log.js:34
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
c:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\utils\log.js:34
[nodemon] watching path(s): src\**\*
c:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\utils\log.js:34
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,js
c:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\utils\log.js:34
[nodemon] starting `node --nolazy -r ts-node/register .\dist\main.js`
c:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\utils\log.js:34

[WEB] http://localhost:3000
```

Can anyone figure out why changes are not taking effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63325135/7625979

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "run",
          "start:debug",
          "--",
          "--inspect-brk"
        ],
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
        "restart": true,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
      }
    ]
  }
```

This solution indeed works for me perfectly and does not need either the vscode's setting: Debug > Javascript: Auto Attach Filter to "Always". Also console: integratedTerminal -option is handy because debug-info comes directly into the same console. Also, nodemon-debug.json is not now needed.

Script command in Package.json file are now:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    ...
}
```

It seems that "--watch" is still needed here for the code changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a launch.json in my NestJS project in VSCode.

However, I did change the debug settings in VSCode to the following:

```
file -> preferences -> settings -> Debug > Javascript: Auto Attach Filter to "Always"
```

[image]

Then when I set a breakpoint my test stops on the breakpoint. If I make a change and save the file my test will restart automatically and stop on the breakpoint with the updated values.

Comment: This has no influence on the issue. Somehow the process debugger is using has no access to the changed code, it just uses the old version of the code that existed before the debugging session was launched.

Comment: I also have this in the scripts section of my package.json  - "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",

Comment: I see, many kids of configurations can work. I might try this one as well, to just test if it work in my environment. Interestingly, it is also referring to jest in node_modules.